# How to call CreateApiView and ListApiView using same url conf in django-rest-framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to build a `GET` and `POST` method to get and save some objects.
I have `views.py` like this

```
class QuestionList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Question.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuestionSerializer

class QuestionSave(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Question.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuestionSerializer
```

Then I have url conf, `urls.py` like this

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^questions/$',views.QuestionList.as_view())
    ]
```

In my understanding, we have to have a generic class with CreateApiView for `POST` methods and ListApiView for `GET` method and so I have created classes like that.
My question is, how should I configure them so that on `POST` QuestionSave will be called and on `GET` QuestionList will be called?

Comment: why not `QuestionList(generics.ListAPIView, generics.CreateAPIView)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ListCreateAPIView. It provides get and post method handlers for a view.

Refer: [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listcreateapiview)

```
class QuestionView(generics.ListCreateAPIView)
    queryset = Question.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuestionSerializer
```

Comment: thanks for the answer and it worked but now I am getting 'this field is required' error. Can you help me on this one as well?

Comment: Sure. Post the code for your model's serializer and model

Comment: The error for 'this field is required' is raised when you're not sending a particular field in post request, but it is required in your model or serializer.

Answer (score 2):

Simple!:

```
class QuestionList(generics.ListAPIView, generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Question.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuestionSerializer
```